# Error Bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

Toda vez que rodo `bundle install` aparece esse erro.

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Você está no diretório correto? 
está usando RVM?

Comment: Sim estou no diretorio, eu to usando rbenv

Comment: Tenta atualizar a rubygems `gem update --system`